# How to style polymer elements that extend HTML elements

Tags: css, dart, dart-polymer

I created the default sample web project in the dart editor, and changed the `<click-counter></click-counter>` element to extend a `DivElement` so it is:

`<div is="click-counter"></div>`

(I changed all HTML and dart files accordingly).

The element is working as expected, but lost all styling in Firefox (30.0). (It works properly in Chrome).

Is this a bug in Firefox?

**EDIT**: To be clear, the CSS is defined in the `clickcounter.html` file.

Comment: Which Dart version are you using? Was the unchanged element displyed correctly in FF?

Comment: Tried with 1.4 and 1.5. The unchanged element worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a normal custom element the elements style is copied to the `<head>` element, this isn't done if the element is an element that extends a DOM element.

This is the CSS Polymer should create in the `<head>` tag for your `<div is='click-counter'>` element.
(It is obviously a bug that it doesn't create this style. You already created the issue https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19841)

```dart
<style shim-shadowdom-css="">style { display: none !important; }
  div[is='click-counter'] div {
    font-size: 24pt; text-align: center; margin-top: 140px;
  }

  div[is='click-counter'] button {
    font-size: 24pt; margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
</style>
```